Flag for company part of a brand
I have table in Power BI, which has list of company grouped into Brands. If a company has a certain brand (brand is selected by the user from the slicer), then that company should be flagged along with all other brands.
User selected from the slicer = B1

I am looking for a DAX calculation to generate Flag (custom measure/column) in the given image

The Brand slicer is disconnected from the visual?

Yes, there are 2 brand tables, one is part of the model with relationship and other is stand alone with in any relationship. The user select is from disconnected table.
